# When I drop a node on the screen, then the mouse event does not pick it up again

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have written a simple script to drag and drop an area2d node but when I drop it somewhere on the left of the screen, then the mouse event does not pick it up again. Any ideas as to what the problem is?
Here's my code:

```
    extends Area2D

var selected: bool = false

func _process(_delta):
    if selected:
        position = get_global_mouse_position()


func _on_pin_input_event(_viewport, event, _shape_idx):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT:
        if event.pressed:
            selected = true
        else: 
            selected = false
```

I have tried changing the screen resolution and the problem persists. I have also set the mouse to ignore on all control and sprite nodes so that's also not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There was an old scene I used for scene transitions and it was stopping the mouse input.